# I couldn't add a Scaffolded item in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

While working on my asp.net core 6 project i tried to add a scaffolded[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkLyR.png) item to my HastaneRandevuSistemi1.web project but it gives me that there are no scaffolders supported for this item.

i tried to add a scaffolded item but it doesnt support it

Comment: Your Web project seems to have some dependency issues(after looking at the image you posted). Try resolving those.

Comment: @Ghaith welcome to SO. what actions have you done. please edit your question and give more details.